# Angularjs Controller Reload

Tags: angularjs, controller, ionic-framework

I am new in ionic. I created a sidemenu based app in that after login I am displaying a number of tasks if click on task it will redirect to task details page in that page I can update the tasks. So after updating a task I need to go back to previous task list page .I am using $ionicHistory.goBack(); for go back.

My problem is after come back I need to refresh the task list i.e. updated task should not be there in the task list how can I refresh/reload the task list? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `$state.go('name-of-task-list-state');` to go to the task list.

Can you show the code you use for updating the task?

Answer (score 0):

Add cache-view="false"  default is true